# SQL return 1 in case switch when count is bigger than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an input list of int in a stored procedure, every id has a document, and every document has multiple subdocuments. Connected on `subdocument.DocumentId = document.DocumentId`.

What I have to do is return a list of objects (`document.DocumentId int, IsValid bool`).

The bool is true if every connected subdocument's 2 columns are not null.

PARAMLIST: list of ids

```
SELECT 
    IDS.ParamList AS documentId,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) 
              FROM Document D
              JOIN SubDocument SD ON SD.DocumentId = D.DocumentId
              WHERE SD.DocumentId = IDS.ParamList 
                AND SD.PaymentDate IS NULL 
                AND SD.ConnectionContractIsAcceptedDate IS NULL) > 0
             THEN 1
             ELSE 0 
    END AS IsValid
FROM 
    @documentIds IDS
```

As you can see my logic was to make a case switch where I count every `SubDocument` which doesn't have at least one of the columns filled, but the query doesn't return anything just the 2 column names

Document table:

| DocumentId | CreatedBy |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John |
| 2 | Jill |

SubDocument table:

| SubDocumentId | DocumentId | Field1 | Field2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 | NULL | 2010-02-02 |
| 4 | 2 | 2021-01-01 | 2018-03-03 |
| 5 | 1 | 2020-10-10 | 2015-11-15 |
| 6 | 2 | 2019-10-01 | 2013-12-12 |

Here the expected result is:

| DocumentId | IsValid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | false |
| 2 | true |

Comment: Why `SELECT COUNT(*)` why not just `CASE WHEN EXISTS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join the table variable to the tables.
Then use conditional aggregation to calculate IsValid.

> ```
> declare @DocumentIds table (
>  DocumentId int
> );
>
> insert into @DocumentIds values (1),(2);
>
> SELECT Doc.DocumentId, Doc.CreatedBy
> , CAST(MIN(
>       CASE
>       WHEN (SubDoc.Field1 IS NULL OR SubDoc.Field2 IS NULL) 
>       THEN 0
>       ELSE 1
>       END) AS BIT) AS IsValid
> FROM Document Doc
> JOIN @DocumentIds Ids 
>   ON Ids.DocumentId = Doc.DocumentId
> LEFT JOIN SubDocument SubDoc
>   ON SubDoc.DocumentId = Doc.DocumentId
> GROUP BY Doc.DocumentId, Doc.CreatedBy
> ORDER BY Doc.DocumentId;
> ```

| DocumentId | CreatedBy | IsValid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | False |
| 2 | Jill | True |

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=588c25eb58da9e751d5660910b7de6a6)*